# Does anyone know where I can find the reaction rate coefficient and design equation for the electrolysis of brine and sodium hydroxide solution?

Tags: physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, electrochemistry, electrolysis, reaction-control

equation 1) $\ce{2 Cl^{–} -> Cl_2 + 2e^{-}}$

equation 2) $\ce{2 H2O + 2 e^{–} -> H2 + 2OH^{–}}$

These equations are the key reactions in the chlor-alkali process. I want to model a reactor for this process based on a CSTR (continuous stirred tank reactor). However I really need reaction rate coefficients (k values) and design equations. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do You have the meanst knowledge on electrolysis? Reaction rate is determied by the current you apply, up to some saturation value, in this case the saturation is reached when the electrodes are covered by the gases evolved. CSTRs and electrolysis is pure nonsense.

Comment: Actually, the book I am referring too, 'Electrochemical Engineering by H.Wendt' explains in section 6.5.2 that a CSTR is a good approximation for the cell design as the cell is intrinsically well stirred by gas evolution. The reaction rate constant can be determined via the applied current.

Answer (score 4):

You should look in some kind of reaction rate database, e.g. [NIST](http://kinetics.nist.gov/kinetics/welcome.jsp). An example from the database: [image]